# typeerror cannot read property 'match' of undefined - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to add an another text field where user can search his notes in that filed but i am unable to do so , when i try below method i get error as `typeerror cannot read property 'match' of undefined`  and the notes are not getting filtered

component.html

```
<input type="text" #notes class="form-control" placeholder="Add Notes" name="notes" [(ngModel)]="inputNotes" >
<span class="input-group-text" (click)="addNote(notes.value)">Add</span>

//Search field
              <input type="text" #notes class="form-control" placeholder="Add Notes" name="notes"  (input)="Search()">
```

Component.ts

```
 inputNotes: string = ""
  notesArray = []
  addNote(value) {
    if (value !== "") {
      this.notesArray.push(value)
    }
    else {
      alert('Field required **')
    }
    console.log(this.inputNotes)
  }

//Search filed
Search(value: string) {
    
    this.notesArray = this.notesArray.filter(res => {
      return res.value.match(this.notesArray)
    })
  }
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: implementation within the `array.filter` function is wrong. You're trying to use `value` from your params but it's actually the `value` key in `res` (which does not exist). Compare the element instead using `===` with your `value` param.

Comment: You get your error message because the elements in your `this.notesArray` do not have a property called value. So `res.value` is undefined. You are trying to call `match` on that `undefined` value. Also there are plenty of other odd things going on in the code. You may want to review it line-by-line and read up on some things. Did you do the basic angular tutorial yet? https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't send any values to your `Search` method from your input. I suggest using [Two-way binding](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding) and then just call the `Search` method.

Second, your `notesArray` is probably holding strings. So , for the items in your `notesArray` there is no such property `value`.

Comment: i have removed value in Search function parameter and tried `return res.match(this.notesArray)` but it returns nothing and my notes disappear ,
 i am totally new to Angular so need help

Comment: @Meh `const criteria = value;
    const result = this.notesArray.filter(item => item === criteria);
      return result` this isnt working